# How to avoid setState() inside render() when state depends on render

Tags: reactjs

I have a grid that renders cards of variable heights.

To get the height of the cards, I render the card wrapped in `ReactHeight` (https://github.com/nkbt/react-height), which lets me pass a callback function to it when the height is ready.

I keep the card heights in an array in the component `state`, which I update as card heights get reported.

When all heights are available, I calculate the padding from the heights, which `render` passes to the cards

In a simplified version, it looks like this.

```
class Grid extends Component {
  constructor() {
    ...
    this.state = { cardHeights: {}, paddings: [] }; //initial state
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    const i = setInterval(() => {
      if (all heights are ready) {
        // ...calculate paddings
        this.setState(paddings: calculatedPaddings);

        clearInterval(i);
      }
    }, 100);
    // *A*
  }

  updateCardHeights(index, height) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      cardHeights: {
        ...prevState.cardHeights,
        [index]: height,
      },
    }));
  }

  render() {
    // index = cards are indexed like 1   2  3
    //                                4   5  6
    //                                7   8  9
    //                                10 11 12
    //                                     ...
    return (
      <ReactHeight onHeightReady={ height => this.updateCardHeights(index, height) }
         <Card padding={this.state.paddings[index]}/>
      </ReactHeight>
    );

  }
}
```

I know `setState()` calls `render`, and calling a function mutating the state inside `render` generally leads to an infinite loop.

In my code, `render` calls a function that updates `this.state.cardHeights` array, and the rendering of its child component, `Card`, indirectly depends on `this.state.cardHeights`, since `this.state.paddings` that it directly depends on is calculated based on cardHeights on `componentDidUpdate()`.

However, I cannot get the height of the `Card` component without rendering it, so the only way I can think of is making `padding` a `prop` to card and state of the component, and then changing the state after rendering.

My question is:

1. Somehow my code didn't result in an infinite loop even though I'm changing state inside render, but is a better way to do this?
2. `clearInterval()` inside my `componentDidUpdate()` function doesn't seem to work. I put a print statement in `*A*` part, and it keeps printing even when the if condition is met and `clearInterval()` is supposedly called. Can this be because of my bad state mutation?

Comment: What's the `index` here?

Comment: maybe you can use `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)`. Read more here: 
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In such case you should check if the previous value and the new value are same before updating the state. I hope your height does not gets updated for each render. So you can have a check in`updateCardheights` to determine if there is an actual change and then update the state. This ensures that it does not updates the state for redundant updates. But if on each render your state is going to be updated, then the problem would remain the same.

```
updateCardHeights(index, height) {
 if(this.state.cardHeights[index] !== height) {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
   cardHeights: {
     ...prevState.cardHeights,
     [index]: height,
   },
  }));
 }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I did, but I added a few more condition checks here and there.

Answer (score -2):

I have following solution regarding your issue above.
Just assign the event handler outside the render function. And do not forget to bind your event handler inside the constructor. After that you can call that event handler inside your render function